# Woocommerce - Changing font size and color in products page

Tags: css, woocommerce

I'm trying to change the font size and color of product's price in the products page. I added this to my custom css to try to override the original css, but no matter what, it does not work.

```
.woocommerce ul.products li.product .price {color:#ec7f91;font-size:16px;}
```

or

```
.woocommerce ul.products li.product .price {color:#ec7f91;font-size:16px;!important}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it's probably because all the other styles are overwriting it.

Second, the `!important` needs to be on both, not just one, and it needs to be inside the semicolon.

Fixed up code:

```
.woocommerce ul.products li.product .price {
    color:#ec7f91 !important;
    font-size:16px !important;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it was actually a stupid css mistake I made, closed a css block with { and not }, it didn't mess with anything else so it took me a while to notice.

Comment: @Dragonflylib OK, glad you got the problem!